# Typescript conversion of string to integer

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to convert a string to an integer in TypeScript, this is done with the `parseInt` method. Here is the issue the string is coming from and environmental variable so its type is `string || undefined` but the `parseInt` method requires an argument of type `string`. How can I solve the typescript error of the wrong argument type to the `parseInt` method? since the process.env is of type `string || undefined`.

Comment: If you share the code snippet, a more detailed and useful solution can be found.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from `parseInt`, we also have an alternative to convert a **string** to a **number** using unary `+` operator with string...

```
function parse_using_parseInt(string_as_number: string | undefined) {
    if((string_as_number || '').trim()) {
        return parseInt((string_as_number || '').trim(), 10);
    }
    return NaN;
}

function parse_using_plus(string_as_number: string | undefined) {
    if((string_as_number || '').trim()) {
        return +(string_as_number || '').trim();
    }
    return NaN;
}
```

Check the examples and pick what is suitable.

---

### ***Illustration***

```js
"use strict";

function parse_using_parseInt(string_as_number) {
  if ((string_as_number || '').trim()) {
    return parseInt((string_as_number || '').trim(), 10);
  }
  return NaN;
}

function parse_using_plus(string_as_number) {
  if ((string_as_number || '').trim()) {
    return +(string_as_number || '').trim();
  }
  return NaN;
}
console.log('Using parseInt: ', parse_using_parseInt(undefined));
console.log('Using parseInt: ', parse_using_parseInt("undefined"));
console.log('Using parseInt: ', parse_using_parseInt("123"));
console.log('Using parseInt: ', parse_using_parseInt("123xyz")); //<-- Partially parsed as 123, What is expected for this input
console.log('Using parseInt: ', parse_using_parseInt("xyz123"));
console.log('Using plus: ', parse_using_plus(undefined));
console.log('Using plus: ', parse_using_plus("undefined"));
console.log('Using plus: ', parse_using_plus("123"));
console.log('Using plus: ', parse_using_plus("123xyz")); //<-- This parses as NaN, unlike parseInt
console.log('Using plus: ', parse_using_plus("xyz123"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use an if statement.

```
if(value === undefined) return;
return parseInt(value);
```

In this way, you will also prevent an error that may occur.